# How to add custom js to the order_status.phtml

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to add custom js to the order_status.phtml file. where to add the js file and link it to the order_status.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have custom module and want to include custom JS than you can follow below steps.

**Paste your file to custom theme same as core file path and write below code within phtml file.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],
    function($){

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('WOrking');
        });
    });
```

Comment: worked. I appreciate your kind help

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom js in sales_order_view XML

```
<head>
 <link src="Namespace_Modulename::js/custom.js"/>
</head>
```

the custom js will add in view/adminhtml/web/js folder.

Comment: The answer should be more descriptive like location of `sales_order_view`, how to override in theme, what is  `Namespace_Modulename` here, what will be the location of `js` file!